# GCP Vertex AI Pipelines static outound IP address

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a way to get Vertex AI Pipelines to use a static egress IP address so we can whitelist it on a set of APIs?

Something like making it use a certain VPC and hence the NAT associated with that VPC.